# Write key and value to JSON file based on the data provided using Cypress

Tags: json, cypress

I have to write the captured data from the application in JSON file as like below:

```js
    let expectedKey = 'PaperCode';
    cy.get('app-screen').find('#code-details').invoke('val').as(code);
    cy.get('@code').then(code) => {
        cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/applicationDetails.json').then((appDetails) => {
            if(expectedKey === 'StudentCode'){
                appDetails.StudentCode = code;
            }
            if(expectedKey === 'DepartmentCode'){
                appDetails.DepartmentCode = code;
            }
            if(expectedKey === 'PaperCode'){
                appDetails.PaperCode = code;
            }
            if(expectedKey === 'ResultsCode'){
                appDetails.ResultsCode = code;
            }
        })
    })
```

Here, the key and its value are added to json in multiple if blocks. Still, there are many if blocks to implement based on different codes. I want to remove the if blocks and need to add the key and its value to json file based on the expectedKey. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Using bracket notation `appDetails[expectedKey]` to define the new property,

```js
let expectedKey = 'studentCode';
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/applicationDetails.json').then((appDetails) => { 

  cy.get('app-screen').find('#code-details').invoke('val')
    .then(code) => {
      appDetails[expectedKey] = code;  // add (or overwrite) new key
      cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/applicationDetails.json', appDetails)
    })
})
```

---

**Clearing the file of all keys except the one you want**

```js
const expectedKey = 'studentCode';
const appDetails = {}

cy.get('app-screen').find('#code-details').invoke('val')
  .then(code) => {
    appDetails[expectedKey] = code;  // add (or overwrite) new key
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/applicationDetails.json', appDetails)
  })
```

Comment: Hi, a query on this. I have already stored data in this JSON file. I want to clear it first and then update with the new values with the code you have mentioned above. Is that possible?

Comment: Yep! You can use `cy.readFile()` to load the file, use a `.then()` to grab the value, `JSON.parse(value)` to parse the value into JSON, and then the two lines in the above `.then()` to write the value to file.

Comment: @saran if you want to clear all keys, don't read the file just create a new one. Otherwise the above overwrites any current value for `expectedKey`.

Comment: @agoff Cypress automatically parses the json based on file extension.

Comment: Ahh you're right, confused myself with how `cy.request()` needs the body parsed... Don't know where my mind is :D

Comment: The reason for asking to clear all keys and its values from json file is, yesterday, I had ran the tests and stored a set of data as key value pairs in json file. Today, while running the same set of tests, a couple of tests didn't store the data in json as required due to some issue. But, it took the old data (yesterday's) data from json file and executed the tests. If I could clear the data inside the json file upfront, it would be good.